# Coercion of newtyped reader monad given coercion for its value type

Tags: haskell, coercion, type-level-computation

A typeclass `C` with associated data family `X` requires a function `coerceX`. If I implement the typeclass like below, how do I write `coerceX`?

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Type.Coercion
import Control.Monad.Reader

data (T r t)

class C t where
  data X t :: * -> *
  coerceX :: Coercion a b -> Coercion (X t a) (X t b)

instance (C t) => C (T r t) where
  newtype X (T r t) a = X (Reader r (X t a))
  coerceX = ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can lead GHC by the nose through the necessary coercions, like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
instance (C t) => C (T r t) where
  newtype X (T r t) a = X (Reader r (X t a))
  coerceX :: forall a b. Coercion a b -> Coercion (X (T r t) a) (X (T r t) b)
  coerceX Coercion
    = gcoerceWith (coerceX Coercion :: Coercion (X t a) (X t b)) $
        (Coercion :: Coercion (X (T r t) a) (Reader r (X t a))) `trans`
        (Coercion :: Coercible a' b' => Coercion (Reader r a') (Reader r b')) `trans`
        (Coercion :: Coercion (Reader r (X t b)) (X (T r t) b))
```

Once the pattern match:

```
coerceX Coercion = ...
```

brings `Coercible a b` into scope, I think you need to explicitly invoke `coerceX` for the `C t` instance to get `Coercion (X t a) (X t b)`.  I don't see how GHC could deduce this automatically.

Now, in an ideal world, it would be then enough to write:

```
coerceX Coercion = gcoerceWith (coerceX Coercion :: Coercion (X t a) (X t b)) Coercion
```

and with `Coercible (X t a) (X t b)` in scope, GHC would be able to infer the representational equality of `Reader r (X t a)` and `Reader r (X t b)` and consequently the representation equality of `X (T r t) a` and `X (T r t) b`, but it can't quite make this leap.

Answer (score 1):

You can pattern match with the constructor `Coercion` and use the same constructor `Coercion` for the new value. The pattern matching will bring the constraint `Coercible a b` in scope, and using `Coercion` for the result will use that constraint to prove the wanted `Coercible (X (T r) a) (X (T r) b)`.

Pragmatically, this compiles. The magic happens in the last line, where the compiler automatically infers the constraint brought into scope, and the constraint needed for the result to type check. The compiler then verifies that the assumed constraint indeed implies the required one, for the given definition of `data X (T r) a`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Type.Coercion
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader

class C t where
  data X t :: * -> *
  coerceX :: Coercion a b -> Coercion (X t a) (X t b)

data T r = Unused

instance C (T r) where
  newtype X (T r) a = X (Reader r a)
  coerceX Coercion = Coercion
```

---

The question changed since the above answer was written.

For the updated question, I think we need to require a quantified constraint to make it type check:

```
instance
    (forall a b . Coercible a b
               => Coercible (X (T r t) a) (X (T r t) b))
    => C (T r t) where
  newtype X (T r t) a = X (Reader r (X t a))
  coerceX :: Coercion a b -> Coercion (X (T r t) a) (X (T r t) b)
  coerceX Coercion = Coercion
```

I am not sure about how this will be used later on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, chi. My problem is actually more complicated, could you please take another look at the edited question?

Comment: I forgot to add the (C t) constraint to my implementation so I've edited again. It must somehow be possible to use the coerceX from (C t), but pattern matching on the type-applied version doesn't seem to do the trick.